# Weird line breaks in code in mobile view on IOS

Tags: bug, code-formatting, mobile-web

See e.g. [this recent answer of mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268443/874188) The mobile view shows a line break in the middle of the keyword `next` even though there is a longer line just below it which isn't wrapped at all.

Screen shot:

[image: script with line break in ne/xt]

Here I have scrolled the code block to show the end of the longer line underneath:

[image: scrolled to the right, break is still there, near the left margin now]

Screen shots are from Chrome on a fully updated iPhone S, but I've seen this in Safari and some other less-known browsers too. (This is a model with a small screen by today's standards; same as the original iPhone 5.)

I have noticed this a few times recently - off the cuff I'd guess this has been there for about a week.

Is there something weird in the CSS?

Comment: What specific browser/os combination are you using?  I was unable to reproduce with narrow view ports in FF/Chrome on W10.  Neither did any wrapping of text within the code blocks, which makes me suspect it might be your mobile browser trying to insert its own cleverness not any of SO's CSS.

Comment: Quote: *"Screen shots are from Chrome on a fully updated iPhone S."* Is there something crucial missing? And like I also mention this isn't only on Chrome.

Comment: Chrome version 78.0.3904.84

Comment: My glasses apparently.  AFAIK all iOS browsers use the same rendering engine as Safari internally, so if it was broken in one I'd assume all others would have the same problem.

Comment: Also no issues with Chrome on android, so it appears this is an iOS only issue.

Comment: That would be a Safari bug with `white-space: pre` + `word-wrap: break-words`. [Here is an min-repro](https://jsfiddle.net/5vhez92f/) that shows the buggy behavior on desktop version of Safari too. Now, SO team could also decide to remove this `word-wrap: break-words` to a `word-wrap: normal` rule since it doesn't seem quite useful to allow breaking words in a pre.